# Is there any Firefox Addon to find ASP.NET page viewstate size?

Tags: asp.net, viewstate, firefox-addon

Is there any firefox addon which can display my asp.net page viewstate size.... Any suggestion...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, google shows [Firefox Viewstate Size](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5956)

Comment: Unfortunatly, it's not yet compatible with Firefox 4 :/

Comment: Work now perfectly in Firefox 4 and 5

Comment: @Ubikuity : could you explain how you make it works with FF >= 4.0 ? These versions have no status bar and plugin is supposed to show viewstate size at that place.

Comment: @tigrou the status bar has been replaced by the "addon bar", which is hidden by default.  There's an option to enable it, or press "ctrl + /" to toggle it

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this won't work in your situation but have you tried just enabling tracing on the page in question?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94c55d08(VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to work in any browser is to show view state size on the window.status bar, this saves you having to open refresh any external windows.

For example on my base page I do this:-

```
protected override void OnPreRender(System.EventArgs e)
{
  #if DEBUG
  ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(string), "ViewStateSize", "<script language='javascript'>window.status='ViewState size: ' + document.forms[0].__VIEWSTATE.value.length;</script>" );
  #endif
  base.OnPreRender(e);
}
```

Comment: i don't think most browsers really support window.status anymore, but i like the overall concept.  just inject a div or something instead.

Answer (score 0):

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5956